# Convert data of 1 column to multiple columns per user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables which are created with a stored procedure.
[Visualization first and second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mfso.png).

The first table is created based on the id the user selects.

The second table is created when the user selects two filter. These filters are then added in the binding table.

The result table should use the first table to get all the data and the second one to match the correct region and function per user.

The result should be like this:
[Image result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEDRf.png)

Is it possible to get all the regions in one column and all the matching functions in that region in the another column based on the binding table?

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below sql returned the same result like your [Image result table].

try to run below sql in your Oracle.

is this what you want?

```
WITH
    COUNTS AS (
        SELECT 120 AS id, 1 AS persionId, 'Region' AS tellingName, 'RegionX' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 120 AS id, 2 AS persionId, 'Region' AS tellingName, 'RegionX' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 120 AS id, 3 AS persionId, 'Region' AS tellingName, 'RegionY' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 120 AS id, 1 AS persionId, 'Function' AS tellingName, 'FunctionX' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 120 AS id, 2 AS persionId, 'Function' AS tellingName, 'FunctionY' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 120 AS id, 3 AS persionId, 'Function' AS tellingName, 'FunctionX' AS tellingValue FROM DUAL
    ),
    BINDING AS (
        SELECT 1 AS seqid, 120 AS id, 'Region' AS "Column", 'Function' AS "Row" FROM DUAL
    ),
    COLUMN_INFO AS (
        SELECT 
            T2.seqid,
            T1.tellingValue AS "Column"
        FROM
            COUNTS T1,
            BINDING T2
        WHERE
            T1.id = T2.id AND
            T1.tellingName = T2."Column"
        GROUP BY T2.seqid, T1.tellingValue
    ),
    ROW_INFO AS (
        SELECT 
            T2.seqid,
            T1.tellingValue AS "Row"
        FROM
            COUNTS T1,
            BINDING T2
        WHERE
            T1.id = T2.id AND
            T1.tellingName = T2."Row"
        GROUP BY T2.seqid, T1.tellingValue
    )
SELECT
    T1.seqid,
    T1."Column",
    T2."Row"
FROM
    COLUMN_INFO T1,
    ROW_INFO T2
WHERE
    T1.seqid = T2.seqid
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! It does give the same result but that was just some dummy data. It is possible that the first table have like 40 000 rows. So I need a dynamic way to show the result.

Comment: of course it can also be used for dynamic i think. just delete COUNTS and BINDING and replace [from tables] to your real table. the dummy data is just for easier to understand.

Comment: I did an update on this post on what I have at the moment. I'll test your answer now.

Comment: At the updated section i've posted modified query that I have at the moment. When execute this query it keeps loading with the message executing query.... Any idea why it doesn't execute?

Comment: perhaps this sql does cross join to get the [Cartesian product] between COLUMN_INFO  and ROW_INFO that bad performance it is. i updated the sql, please match it to yours and try again. (removed distinct, added GROUP BY to COLUMN_INFO and ROW_INFO, removed ORDER BY)

Comment: Your last query returns only 4 rows. The counts table has 140 rows(70 persons have a function and a region so 70*2 = 140). The return table should give 70 records.

Comment: int your example Counts table have 6 record but bindingresult is 4. If your  distinct region * function data count is 4, then bindingresult will return 4 rows.

Comment: It's working now i had to join the userid with eachother: INNER JOIN ROW_INFO T2 ON T1.seqpers = T2.seqpers thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you^_^